# Enable Restlet for CAS 3.5.2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, cas

I have a project with CAS for SSO. Its been enabled for web login and authentication.
Now there is a requirement of enabling restlet module on CAS.
The problem i am facing is that I have CAS 3.5.2 which is not supported any more and we are not open to update CAS. 
There is a module "cas-server-integration-restlet". I am not able to understand its flow. Made many attempts to generate TGT through rest client, but no success so far.

After some research, I made changes in following files:

1) web.xml in cas-server-webapp module:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>restlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.spring.RestletFrameworkServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>root</param-name>
      <param-value>guard</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>restlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cas/v1/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

which ideally I think should point to restlet-servlet.xml file, which in turn injects to the beans.

If anyone has worked on it, what other changes are to be done. Any guidance would be highly appreciated.